# push notification not receiving in an iphone device

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I followed all the steps mentioned in this link, https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/ and I am able to successfully sent push notifications for android phones. But iPhone is not receiving any notification.

I have properly added APNS certificates and 2195, 2196 ports are opened.

In mobilefirst console, push notification section showing my iphone received 10 messages from event sources. When I looked the tomcat logs it showing following warning

```
Nov 05, 2015 3:48:48 PM com.worklight.gadgets.serving.ClientConfigProfileServlet piggybackConfigProfile
WARNING: com.worklight.core.messages:could not piggyback configprofile due to invalid or incomplete headers sent from client
Nov 05, 2015 3:48:48 PM com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.Mediator run()
SEVERE: FPWSE1067E: An Exception occurred in the mediator.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Not yet implemented
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.Mediator.updateDeviceSubscriptionByToken(Mediator.java:130)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator.updateDeviceSubsciption(GCMMediator.java:172)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.sendAndVerify(GCMSender.java:169)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator.sendOrWait(GCMMediator.java:139)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator.sendNotification(GCMMediator.java:128)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.Mediator$2.run(Mediator.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Is above warning is the clue for the issue? If so what I'm missing? Any suggestions will help.

Comment: Do you have fuller logs to provide...?

Answer (score 3):

This was recently resolved.

Visit IBM Fix Central and download the latest iFix for your MobileFirst Platform Foundation release. Use the updated Studio/CLI package to re-build your application.